# Compare Validator in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am try to validate the date by using compare validator. but it is throwing error, This is my code

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
               ID="CompareValidator1" 
               runat="server" 
               Text="*" 
               Display="None" 
               ValidationGroup ="a" 
               ControlToValidate="txtValidate" 
               ValueToCompare='<%# DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>'
               Operator="GreaterThan"   
               Type ="Date" 
               ErrorMessage="Date Should Greater Than Todate">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

The error is :

> The value '' of the ValueToCompare property of 'CompareValidator1'
>   cannot be converted to type 'Date'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Page_Load` method, call `Page.DataBind()`.

This will execute the databinder code when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your Comapre Validator, In Grid or Repeater or it just on page.

if it is not in Grid then you can give ValueToCompare value from code behind. ValueToCompare='<%# DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>'  not actually bind the date. you can check it using fire bug. it not render as date it will display you as string format. so kindly set this value from code behind.
use this code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    CompareValidator1.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

Comment: view your output to put your code like this: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtValidate" Text="<%#DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>"></asp:TextBox>.

Comment: out put will be "<%=DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>" in textbox.

Answer (score -1):

Try '=' instead of '#'. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
               ID="CompareValidator1" 
               runat="server" 
               Text="*" 
               Display="None" 
               ValidationGroup ="a" 
               ControlToValidate="txtValidate" 
               ValueToCompare='<%= DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>'
               Operator="GreaterThan"   
               Type ="Date" 
               ErrorMessage="Date Should Greater Than Todate">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: this not an issue. all runat="server" control not direct bind using <%= %> or <%# %> code.

Comment: check this code <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtValidate" Text="<%=DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>"></asp:TextBox>. what it represent.